# why does it only output 5 when i put <=10 in my for loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multiplesProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int counter2 = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
            int product = num * counter2;
            System.out.println(num + "x" + counter2 + "=" + product);
            i++;
            counter2++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code and the output is :

```
2x1=2
2x2=4
2x3=6
2x4=8
2x5=10
```

I put <= 10 in my for loop why does it show 5 and not 10;

Comment: As an aside, it would be worth learning about debuggers at this point. This is a question which would definitely lend itself to being diagnosed with a debugger - step through the code and look at how the value of `i` changes.

Answer (score 12):

You're incrementing `i` in two places - once in the `for` loop "header":

```
for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
```

and once in the body of the loop:

```
System.out.println(num + "x" + counter2 + "=" + product);
i++;
counter2++;
```

If you print out `i` on each iteration, you'll see it has values 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.

You almost certainly don't want that `i++;` statement in the body of the loop.

In fact, I'd then change the code to remove `counter2` entirely, as you'd want it to have the same value as `i` on each iteration:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    int product = num * i;
    System.out.println(num + "x" + i + "=" + product);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have "i++" in your for loop with is incrementing your for loop again.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `i++` twice.  Once inside of the loop and once inside of the `for` condition which will make `i` increment twice every loop.

Solution: Remove `i++` from inside the loop.

Additionally, there is no reason for you to use `counter2++` at all in this program.  Instead of `num * counter2` just do `num * i` and you will get the same result and you will not need all the extra fluff.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
```

and here:

```
i++;
```

You are incrementing i **twice** per loop iteration, thus you get only *half* of the expected loop runs out if your code!

So you either want to double your loop limit (10 -> 20), or, more reasonable: drop that second `i++` within your loop body...

Comment: @GladimirDungo You are welcome. And dont forget to accept one of the many answers you got here ;-)